# xna 4.0 Methods of 3D Collision?

Tags: xna, collision

Doing collision and just finished boundingbox and boundingsphere, what other methods of collision are there?

Answer (score 1):

[realtimerendering.com](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) has a table with different types of collisions and the algorithms to detect them.